# Searching Multiple Criteria In Large Data Set to make new Data Set Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, filtering

I have a very large data set that gets updated multiple times a day. It can vary from 1000-20000 entries. I have a macro in place that searches for specific criteria and makes a new table from that data and works but it takes a very long time to sift through all the points. I want to know if there is a more eloquent way to achieve the same result.

I tried a new different methods of the same thing. Poked around at other solutions but could not get them to fit what I needed. I even tried the advanced filtering tables but to no avail.

```
Function AgedDivert()
    
    'Pull from scraped data to display compact data set
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    ufProgress.Caption = "Loading Aged Divert"
    ufProgress.LabelProgress.Width = 0
    
    pasterow = 31
    sname = "Aged Divert Report"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sname).Rows(30 & ":" & 999999).Clear
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp").Range("1:1").Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sname).Range("30:30")
    RowCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Scraped Data").Range("A:A"))
    'Create new data sort by age and location
    For i = 2 To RowCount
        pctComplete = (i - 2) / (RowCount - 2)
        'Filter out Direct Loads, PA2, Less than 180 Minutes, Secondary, not diverted
        If Len(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Scraped Data").Range("D" & i).Value) <> 2 And _
         (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Scraped Data").Range("J" & i).Value = "Ship Sorter" Or _
         ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Scraped Data").Range("K" & i).Value = "Divert Confirm") And _
         ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Scraped Data").Range("D" & i).Value <> "" And _
         ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Scraped Data").Range("M" & i).Value > 180 And _
         ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Scraped Data").Range("I" & i).Value <> "Left to Pick" And _
         InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Scraped Data").Range("C" & i).Value, "Location") = 0 And _
         (InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Scraped Data").Range("C" & i).Value, "Warehouse A") > 0 Or _
         InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Scraped Data").Range("C" & i).Value, "Warehouse C") > 0 Or _
         InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Scraped Data").Range("C" & i).Value, "PA") = 0) Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Scraped Data").Range(i & ":" & i).Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sname).Range(pasterow & ":" & pasterow)
            pasterow = pasterow + 1
        End If
        ufProgress.LabelProgress.Width = pctComplete * ufProgress.FrameProgress.Width
        ufProgress.Repaint
    Next i
    ufProgress.Caption = "Loading Complete. Cleaning Data"
    
    'Remove Unnecessary Data
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sname).Columns("R").Delete
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sname).Columns("Q").Delete
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sname).Columns("O").Delete
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sname).Columns("N").Delete
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sname).Columns("L").Delete
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sname).Columns("K").Delete
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sname).Columns("J").Delete
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sname).Columns("H").Delete
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sname).Columns("F").Delete
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sname).Columns("E").Delete
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sname).Range("C30:C999999").Delete
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sname).Range("B30:B999999").Delete
    'Set Data as Table
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sname).ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sname).Range("A30:F" & pasterow), , xlYes).Name = "AgedDivert"
    
    AgedDivert = True
    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    AgedDivert = False
    Debug.Print "Error occured in Aged Divert"
    Debug.Print Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
End Function
```

Comment: Whenever reading or writing to sheets in bulk, it's always best to copy the source data into an array and do your tests there. Then, build an output in the loop array and finally write the entire output array to the output sheet in one go. Lots of examples online.

Comment: RE: Above Comment - "Always best" is an understatement; you could go from a macro that takes 15 minutes to run to 1.2 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the data to an array, filter to another array and copy back to sheet. 20,000 rows should take a few seconds.

```vb
Function AgedDivert()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsReport As Worksheet, wsTemp As Worksheet
    Dim arData, arReport
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, r As Long
    Dim colC, colD, colI, colJ, colK, colM, msg As String
    Dim t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    
    Const RPT_NAME = "Aged Divert Report"
    
    'Pull from scraped data to display compact data set
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    With wb
        Set wsData = .Sheets("Scraped Data")
        Set wsReport = .Sheets(RPT_NAME)
        Set wsTemp = .Sheets("Temp")
    End With
     
    ' copy data
    With wsData
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        ' copy sheet to array
        arData = .Range("A1:P" & lastrow)
        ReDim arReport(1 To lastrow, 1 To 6) ' A to F
        For i = 2 To lastrow
            
            colC = arData(i, 3)
            colD = arData(i, 4)
            colI = arData(i, 9)
            colJ = arData(i, 10)
            colK = arData(i, 11)
            colM = arData(i, 13)
            
            'Filter out Direct Loads, PA2, Less than 180 Minutes,
            'Secondary, not diverted
            If Len(colD) <> 2 And colD <> "" And _
                (colJ = "Ship Sorter" Or colK = "Divert Confirm") _
                And colM > 180 _
                And colI <> "Left to Pick" _
                And InStr(1, colC, "Location") = 0 And _
                (InStr(1, colC, "Warehouse A") > 0 Or _
                InStr(1, colC, "Warehouse C") > 0 Or _
                InStr(1, colC, "PA") = 0) Then
                
                r = r + 1 ' report row
                arReport(r, 1) = arData(i, 1) ' A
                arReport(r, 2) = arData(i, 4) ' D
                arReport(r, 3) = arData(i, 7) ' G
                arReport(r, 4) = arData(i, 9) ' I
                arReport(r, 5) = arData(i, 13) ' M
                arReport(r, 6) = arData(i, 16) ' P
                
             End If
        Next i
    End With
    
    ' output
    With wsReport
        ' delete existing table
        .Rows("30:" & .Rows.Count).Clear
        .Range("A30:F30") = Array("Col A", "Col D", "Col G", "Col I", "Col M", "Col P")
        If r = 0 Then
            MsgBox "No data to report", vbExclamation
        Else
            ' copy rows and set Data as Table
            .Range("A31").Resize(r, 6) = arReport
            .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, .Range("A30:F" & 30 + r), xlYes).Name = "AgedDivert"
        End If
    End With
  
    
    msg = lastrow - 1 & " rows scanned from " & wsData.Name & vbLf & _
          r & " rows copied to " & wsReport.Name
    MsgBox msg, vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")
    
    AgedDivert = True
    Exit Function
    
ErrorHandler:
    AgedDivert = False
    Debug.Print "Error occured in Aged Divert"
    Debug.Print Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
End Function
```